# filetable_updates table in SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-profiler

Recently we started monitoring the `SQL Profiler` to capture queries executed in server.

Strangely we observed the below query executed for every single minute in Database.

```
SELECT table_id,
       item_guid,
       oplsn_fseqno,
       oplsn_bOffset,
       oplsn_slotid
FROM   [Databasename].[sys].[filetable_updates_2105058535] WITH (readpast)
ORDER  BY table_id
```

[image]

When I tried to execute manually, it throwing error saying

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name
>   'Databasename.sys.filetable_updates_2105058535'.

It is using **`sys`** schema not **`dbo`**

Can somebody give insight of this process. Is this something to worry about I searched through forum didn't get any answer. Sometimes it is executing more than twice for a minute

Comment: may be this query included in function or procedure. And that procedure called every minute by JOB scheduler.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale - Not at all.. We dont have any table like this in our database plus we don't have any procedures executed for every single minute through job

Comment: check program name of it

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale - Application Name is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your database has filestream/filetable, you will see these queries being run by the system occasionally:

```
            select table_id, item_guid, oplsn_fseqno, oplsn_bOffset, oplsn_slotid
            from [database].[sys].[filetable_updates_<some_id>] with (readpast) order by table_id
```

So, may you may want to add additional filtering to the above query to filter those out 
(as long as the filter doesn't accidentally filter out queries you do care about). This is probably a safe addition to that derived table:

```
            AND t.[text] NOT LIKE N'%oplsn_fseqno%'
```

And one more is
The AlwaysOn feature must be enabled for the server instance ‘xxxxx\SQL2K12’ before you can create an availability group on this instance.
To enable AlwaysOn, open the SQL Server Configuration Manager, select SQL Server Services, right-click the SQL Server instance name, select Properties, and use the AlwaysOn High Availability tab of the SQL Server Properties dialog.

More Info :

1.[System process queries](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96fbdd7c-6518-4138-801c-85d96e50add0/system-process-running-queries-every-25-seconds-against-sql-2012-developer-edition?forum=sqlexpress)

2.[2012 AlwaysON Setup](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups/)

please let us know if you have any concerns.